# www.mySITE.com is currently unable to handle this request. 500

Tags: php, error, file-permissions, http-error-500

Magento 1.9.1.0

Something happened and customers are getting the following Error when clicking on the CHECK-OUT button:

```
The www.mySITE.com page isn’t working

www.mySITE.com is currently unable to handle this request.
500
```

I suspect this has to do with some kind of an upgrade I bet my hosting provider (HostForWeb) did.

**What are the correct versions (requirements) of pHp, mySQL and Apache for Magento 1.9.1.0?**

Any other ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a server error. if you have a developer store, please go to `index.php` under your root magento store and enable developer mode. Just paste this code after line 72 `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` and uncomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if it is commented. Then you are able to view the error and can research for it on google or can comment here.

Comment: Thank you - that helped. We ended up changing the  'memory_limit = 32M' to 'memory_limit = 512M' in:

/opt/cpanel/ea-php55/root/etc/php.d/local.ini